# getRange(string) works but getRange(number) fails

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Below is code without an explanation, that i will add later, as SO doesn't like something.  I will keep adding to this section until it is happy, and then paste in the actual later.  Basically just look for comment lines 'works' and 'fails'... actually, i finally added a comment below, as SO seems to not like it in the body... sorry...

```
 /*
 * Sends emails with data from the current spreadsheet.
 */
function sendEmails() {
  //var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var fred = "test";
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("18ewaD4ruwR5apY4eEFRlO9m2WfgsgwrEgtfEAPqqAeM");
  var startRow = 2; // First row of data to process
  var numRows = 2; // Number of rows to process
  // Fetch the range of cells A2:B3

  //works... var dataRange = sheet.getRange("A2:B3");
  //fails... var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 2);

  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  
  
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i in data) {
    var row = data[i];
    var emailAddress = row[0]; // First column
    var message = row[1]; // Second column
    var subject = 'Sending emails from a Spreadsheet';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  }
}
```

One line (marked) works, the other (marked) fails with error:

> Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange. (line 14, file "Code")

The failing one comes right from sample, so not sure WHY it is failing... The spreadsheet contains 3 rows: #1 headings for 2 columns #2 firstemail@gmail.com #3 secondemail@gmail.com

Comment: One line (marked) works, the other (marked) fails with error:
Exception: The parameters (String,number,number,number) don't match the method signature for SpreadsheetApp.Spreadsheet.getRange. (line 14, file "Code")
The failing one comes right from sample, so not sure WHY it is failing...
The spreadsheet contains 3 rows:
#1 headings for 2 columns
#2 firstemail@gmail.com
#3 secondemail@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

**Issues:**

`SpreadsheetApp.openById("id")` is an instance of the [Spreadsheet class](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet).

However, `getRange` is a method that can be applied to [sheet objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).

**Solution:**

replace:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
```

with **any** of the following:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getSheetByName("sheetName");
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getActiveSheet();
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id").getSheets()[0]; // 0 indicates the 1st sheet
```

or even with the part that you commented out:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
```

Comment: These are much better answers to my specific question and related error than the suggested associated previously answered.  PLEASE do not delete this, as i want it for good reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`getRange()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangea1notation) on a [Spreadsheet object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet), but it requires A1 notation.

The [`getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns) method is only available on [Sheet objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet).